# Optimize profit of a linear matrix where the user can either skip 1 or 2 cells

Tags: c, algorithm, optimization

Instruction: Several cells are arranged one after the other in a straight line. In i-th cell, a given integer ai is written (i=1,2, …, N). I start from the first cell at the left end and move right; I can choose to jump into the next cell, or into the next of the next cell. Every time I entered a cell i, I have to pay | ai | dollars, when ai is negative, or to receive ai dollars, when ai is nonnegative. At most, how many dollars can I earn?

Input: Integer values of N, a1, a2, …., aN, separated by spaces.

Output: One integer equals to the wanted profit.

Constraints: 0 < N < 100; -100 < ai < 100 for each ai.

e.g.

Input: 
7 2 -1 3 –2 -1 6 -5

Output:
10

I have come up with a solution to the problem I believe is correct. However, the submissions tester only gives me 5/10.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int n,array[100];
    int i = 0;
    int sum = 0;


 scanf("%d",&n);
 for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    if(scanf("%d",&array[i])){}
 }

 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 {
     if(array[i] >= 0)
     {
        sum += array[i];
     }
     else if(array[i] < 0 && array[i+1] < 0)
     {
         if(array[i] > array[i+1])
         {
            sum += array[i];
         }
         else if(array[i] <= array[i+1])
         {
             sum += array[i+1];
             i++;
         }
     }
 }

 printf("%d", sum);

 return 0;
}
```

Although I seem to be able to get a solid output after entering randomized input within the constraints, the code only passes 5/10 tests. Would you point out any irregularities that you notice with the code?

Comment: First of all, please don't pick multiple language tags, only the single language you're actually programming in. Secondly, the correct way to solve this kind of problem is to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) your program. However, if the data or input is not known that becomes hard to impossible. That's one reason competition or online judge sites are not really good for teaching the basics of programming. Another is that all you really learn is how to write program for such sites and not much more.

Comment: A consistent indentation would help interpreting your code and hence finding errors in it.

Comment: Did you progam a brute force solution? Does it pass more tests? Usually they do, but are then rejected for time constrainsts, but that does provide information on whether there are test cases which fail. Looking at your code, it seems that you coded a obvious (not to say short-sighted) algorithm. For correct (but slow) brute force I feel there should be at least two nested loops. E.g. just go through all possible choices (nearly 2 to the power of n, less becaue of the skipped cells for half of the choices). Please do this and report the result.

Comment: Um, I think this is as brute force as they come.

Comment: I may have misinterpreted your instructions, but, given the posted example, why 17 (= 7+2+3-1+6) isn't the correct solution?

Comment: You can skip a single cell( hence the -1 is skipped and the answer is 18).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider

## 0 -1 -2 -1000 0

When `i = 1`, your algorithm will execute the branch on line 25, therefore choosing
**0 -1 -2 0** cells, although the optimal solution is **0 -2 0**